# Rank error in tf.nn.dynamic_rnn

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build a CNN + RNN model and I am getting the following error.
Any help will be appreciated.

> fc2 has shape (?,4096)

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.rnn_hidden_units)
stack = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell]*self.rnn_layers)
initial_state = cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)
initial_state = tf.identity(initial_state, name='initial_state')
outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stack, fc2,dtype=tf.float32)
```

> File "rcnn.py", line 182, in model
>       outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stack, [fc2],dtype=tf.float32)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 574, in dynamic_rnn
>       dtype=dtype)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 637, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
>       for input_ in flat_input)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 637, in 
>       for input_ in flat_input)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 649, in with_rank_at_least
>       raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank at least %d" % (self, rank))
>   ValueError: Shape (4096, ?) must have rank at least 3

Comment: The error seems fairly clear, [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) expects a 3-dimensional tensor as input (i.e. rank 3), but `fc2` has only two dimensions. The shape of `fc2` should be something like `(<batch_size>, <max_time>, <num_features>)` (or `(<max_time>, <batch_size>,
 <num_features>)` if you pass `time_major=True`).

Comment: @jdehesa I am taking an image (for ocr ) and passing it through a CNN and later connecting it to a fully connected layer hence the shape `fc2` is `(?,4096)` , is there some other way to do this then ?

Comment: That's okay, but what would be the "time" dimension then? If you only have one image (that is, a batch of examples, each of which contains one image, I assume), what is the dimension that you want the RNN to iterate? The pixels, kind of like PixelRNN?

Comment: @jdehesa I am following this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03101.pdf . 
They have mentioned an architecture where they are performing character-level-Language modelling from the feature extracted from Image. If you could suggest how can this be implemented, it will be really helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know much about those models... For the character-level modelling, I _think_ it could be something like stacking _N_ copies of the result of the convolution and input it to the RNN, then each _K_-vector output would be the probability of each letter, but I'm not really sure...

Comment: @jdehesa It's ok, thanks for your help!

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: @brw59 the solution that mentioned by iga worked

Comment: How come you didn't mark it as an answer? I assumed that somebody was helped, but it didn't solve your problem because there's, as of now, no check mark

Comment: @brw59 done, i didn't because the first answer was posted a lot later than the one that iga gave, so it got skipped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copying the answer of @jdehesa from his comment for better visibility:

The error seems fairly clear, [tf.nn.dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) expects a 3-dimensional tensor as input (i.e. rank 3), but fc2 has only two dimensions. The shape of `fc2` should be something like `(<batch_size>, <max_time>, <num_features>)` (or `(<max_time>, <batch_size>, <num_features>)` if you pass `time_major=True`)

Answer (score 1):

The default input of tf.nn.dynamic_rnn has a dimension of 3 (Batchsize, sequence_length, num_features). Since your num_features is 1 you can expand your fc_seq with

```
fc2 = tf.expand_dims(fc2, axis = 2)
```

and then use the code you have above.

Comment: Nice, thank you for the hint. For me, this was the missing bit for adding batch dimension to 2D data.